# Same question or not the same question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, bounty

Here are two Stack Overflow questions. One is obviously a duplicate of the other since they were posted at relatively the same time. Both of these questions do not have an accepted answer.

[two-swipe-down-tap-unable-to-catch-on-google-glass-gdk-xe16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218457/two-swipe-down-tap-unable-to-catch-on-google-glass-gdk-xe16)

[capturing-two-swipe-down-on-google-glass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612189/capturing-two-swipe-down-on-google-glass) (duplicate?)

7 months have passed since those questions were asked. Seeing how fast Android (and Google glass) gets updated, should I add a bounty to one of those questions OR just make a  new question? Knowing that the first question mentions the actual Google glass version (XE16).. the version currently out is XE22.

If I hadn't asked this question I would have done whatever was most logical:

Added a bounty to the one that had a comment saying "duplicate of... " since even though it's dated (and probably a duplicate), it doesn't have a version mentioned. Am I wrong?